# How to do long scroll and split screen with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, frontend

I've been checking on the internet how to do a long scroll with split screen in reactjs. I would like to do something like [THIS SITE](http://amalthea.be/).

Is there any component or way to do it? I've found a lot of jquery examples, but any with React.

To add some extra information I'm running react with react-bootstrap, babel(ES6), gulp, browserify, sass and hot load.

Thanks for your help!

Ruffeng

Comment: Or at least if someone has any idea how to do a long scroll I'd really appreciate.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fakoleqowi/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Wow man! You are impressive! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with react-onepage-scroll.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onepage-scroll

Simple and clean. If sbdy know how to apply a split screen I'll appreciate it.